# How to determine device rotation AFTER change in recent iOS versions with Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an embedded web controller in an iPad only app that needs to update the web page AFTER the device has rotated to get viewport sizing correct. I currently am using a deprecated method:

```
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

Apple's documentation says to use the newer:

```
viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:
```

I see lots of similar questions on SO and they all point to this newer method.

Unfortunately, this new method happens BEFORE the device rotates. I need to know when the device rotation happens *AFTER* it rotates. If I use the new method, the web page updates before it the orientation change happens and the sizing on the web page gets all wonky.

Please don't suggest making the web page better. I agree it should happen, but it's out of my control. I need to deal with what is there.

How can I make this happen without an old, deprecated method?

Cheers!
TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `coordinator` to "animate" the rotation and listen for the `completion` callback. You can give `nil` as custom animation parameter:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        print("Rotation finished")
    }
}
```

The code should be self explained.

Edit (ObjC):

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        NSLog(@"Rotation finished");
    }];
}
```

Comment: It's a normal view controller function override. You can easily adapt this. I added the ObjC Code to the answer above

Comment: Brilliant, mate! I do very little work in Obj-C and none in Swift. Just trying to keep a legacy app alive.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews. But this method may be called many number of times in the view's life cycle. You can have a variable viewWidth which has the view's current width. If there is a change in the view's width in viewDidlayoutSubviews, you can conclude there is a change in the layout and you need to reload ur view.

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];


    if (viewWidth == 0)
    {
        viewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width; // First time assign
        return;
    }

  if (viewWidth != self.view.bounds.size.width)
  {
    viewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width; 
    // perform ur reload operation here.
  }
}
```